Is there a way to make the below code more efficient
I want it to run a little faster. Would using a do until or do while loop make it faster?
I tried a for Loop, and was expecting the code to run more smoothly. Please see the code below.
Should I try dim'n the worksheets as well?
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheet2.Cells.ClearContents
Sheets("Sheet1").Select


Dim i As Integer
Dim LastRow1 As Integer
Dim LastRow2 As Integer

LastRow1 = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 1 To LastRow1

If Sheet1.Cells(i, 13) <> "" And IsNumeric(Sheet1.Cells(i, 13)) Then

VendorID = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1)
VendorName = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2)
VendorSite = Sheet1.Cells(i, 4)
VendorInvoice = Sheet1.Cells(i, 5)
VendorDate = Sheet1.Cells(i, 8)
VendorPeriod = Sheet1.Cells(i, 10)
VendorAmount = Sheet1.Cells(i, 11)
VendorCheck = Sheet1.Cells(i, 15)


LastRow2 = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

 Sheet2.Cells(LastRow2, 1) = VendorID
 Sheet2.Cells(LastRow2, 2) = VendorName
 Sheet2.Cells(LastRow2, 3) = VendorSite
 Sheet2.Cells(LastRow2, 4) = VendorInvoice
 Sheet2.Cells(LastRow2, 5) = VendorDate
 Sheet2.Cells(LastRow2, 6) = VendorPeriod
 Sheet2.Cells(LastRow2, 7) = VendorAmount
 Sheet2.Cells(LastRow2, 8) = VendorCheck
 
 End If
 
 
 Next i
 
 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 MsgBox ("DONE")
 
 Sheets("DATA").Select
 Columns.AutoFit



Dim'ing the variables won't improve run-time. You might squeak out a little performance improvement by capturing this: LastRow2 = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 outside the for loop, and then inside the for/if just do LastRow2 = LastRow2 + 1 to increment. You might also want to shut off sheet calculations and then re-enable at the end (like screenupdating).

First, copy your data into an array. Then, run the loop and output your data into a second array. Finally, write the data from the second array to the sheet all at once. That should significantly improve performance.  https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/#How_To_Make_Your_Macros_Run_at_Super_Speed

If you have a new Excel (2021, 365), you can use the FILTER function instead of VBA.

An example of using arrays to speed execution:
Sub XFer()

    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet, cols, i As Long
    Dim data, dataOut, r As Long, rOut As Long, numCols As Long
    
    cols = Array(1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 11, 15) 'columns to be copied over
    numCols = UBound(cols) + 1              'cols is zero-based
    
    Set wsSrc = Sheet1
    'read all input data to an array
    data = wsSrc.Range("A1:O" & wsSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    ReDim dataOut(1 To UBound(data, 1), 1 To numCols) 'size array for output
    
    Set wsDest = Sheet2
    wsDest.Cells.ClearContents
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1) 'scan through input data
        If Len(data(r, 13)) > 0 And IsNumeric(data(r, 13)) Then 'want this line?
            rOut = rOut + 1                  'next output line index
            For i = 1 To numCols
                dataOut(rOut, i) = data(r, cols(i - 1))  'transfer wanted values...
            Next i
        End If
    Next r
    
    If rOut > 0 Then  'any lines to show?
        wsDest.Range("A1").Resize(rOut, numCols).Value = dataOut
        wsDest.Activate
    End If
    
 End Sub


Copy Values From Specified Columns Efficiently
Source

Destination

Sub CopyColumnValues()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const SRC_CRITERIA_COLUMN As Long = 13
    Dim sCols() As Variant: sCols = VBA.Array(1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 11, 15)
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "A2"
    
    ' Reference the worksheets using their code names.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = Sheet1
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = Sheet2
    
    ' Return the values of the source (data) range in a 2D one-based array.
    ' Also, retrieve the number of rows and columns.
    
    Dim Data As Variant, srCount As Long, scCount As Long
    
    ' The source list starts in A1 and has one row of headers.
    With sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        srCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        If srCount = 0 Then
            MsgBox "No data in worksheet """ & sws.Name & """!", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        scCount = Application.Max(sCols, SRC_CRITERIA_COLUMN)
        If scCount > .Columns.Count Then
            MsgBox "Not enough columns!", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Data = .Resize(srCount, scCount).Offset(1).Value
    End With
            
    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = UBound(sCols) + 1
            
    ' Write the matching rows to the top-left of the array.

    Dim sr As Long, dr As Long, dc As Long

    For sr = 1 To srCount
        If VarType(Data(sr, SRC_CRITERIA_COLUMN)) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
            dr = dr + 1
            For dc = 1 To dcCount
                Data(dr, dc) = Data(sr, sCols(dc - 1))
            Next dc
        'Else ' is not a number; do nothing
        End If
    Next sr
    
    ' Copy.
    With dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL).Resize(, dcCount) ' first destination row
        .Resize(dr).Value = Data ' copy values
        .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row - dr + 1).Offset(dr).Clear
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
            
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Column values copied.", vbInformation

End Sub


Using Sheet Objects instead of working with active sheet is usually easier.
Using arrays instead of direct cell manipulation like @Storax commented is also helpful for speed.
Sub Example()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheet2.Cells.ClearContents

Dim vData() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim LastRow1 As Integer
Dim LastRow2 As Integer

LastRow1 = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row

vData = Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1), Sheet1.Cells(LastRow1, 15))

For i = 1 To LastRow1

    If vData(i, 13) <> "" And IsNumeric(vData(i, 13)) Then
        LastRow2 = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Sheet2.Range(Sheet2.Cells(LastRow2, 1), Sheet2.Cells(LastRow2, 8)) = Array(vData(i, 1), vData(i, 2), vData(i, 4), vData(i, 5), vData(i, 8), vData(i, 9), vData(i, 11), vData(i, 15))
    End If
    
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

